# Forcing MATLAB to wait for an external program to finish a DDE command

Tags: matlab, wait, pause, dde

I have a MATLAB script that calls an external program via DDE protocol, I want MATLAB to wait for the execution to end, which is indicated with a 0/1 that is returned from `ddeexec(programName,command)`.

I had no success trying to use `wait` or `waitfor` since they receive an object and I only have a returned value (which is a double).

The temporary solution I have is to use `pause(secToPause)` but it's not a good solution as the external program run time can change.

Note that the external program is always running in the background so checking if the process had finished won't work either.

Any suggestions?

```
osloFinished = 0; %set var to see if OSLO finished its job
osloFinished = ddeexec(OSLO,osloCommand); %send execution to OSLO 
matlabMagicWait %here I want to matlab to stop and wait for osloFinished to change to 1
```

Comment: You didn't indicate what app you are using DDE to communicate with. Does the app have a COM/ActiveX interface that could be used instead of DDE? DDE is very old and the recommended method is to use COM instead. Sorry if this is not of help to you.

Comment: The app is called [OSLO](https://www.lambdares.com/oslo-usonly/) and sadly it is the reason I have to use DDE.

Comment: `ddeexec` and friends haven’t been supported since more than 10 years ago. https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-dde-support

Comment: If there is a command that finishes quickly, you can send this repeatedly and wait for it too succeed. `wait(1)` or so in between sending the commands.